# How to check if flutter app runs in standalone mode or as a module inside of a native app?

Tags: flutter, flutter-module

I'm developing a flutter module for an existing native android app. I made some interop with MethodChannel. Now, for test purposes, I would like to run my module as a standalone app. To do so I mocked all my interop code with dummy placeholders. Now I want to check (programmatically) if flutter runs in standalone mode or is a part of a module, to make a decision on which interop implementation to use (the android one VS the dummy).

Answer (score 2):

My solution is when the app start, try to invoke a method in MethodChannel, if throws MissingPluginException means flutter runs standalone.

```dart
/// check if flutter is run as a moudle embeded in a app project
static Future<bool> get isEmbeded async {
  try {
    await _methodChannel.invokeMethod('Foo');
    return true;
  } on MissingPluginException {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Call this when start, and you can save the result somewhere as a global static variable to avoid future async calls.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30668694)

Comment: I think that in this solution, you have to implement this Foo function as well. Which is less nice

Answer (score 1):

I ended up with this solution so far:

`flutter run --dart-define="standalone=true"`

Using it when building a standalone app.
Then in the code:

`const bool isStandalone = bool.fromEnvironment('standalone');`